# How to make immovable background in iOS?

Tags: ios, uiview, background

In my application, I have UITableViewController, with table on it.
I filling background with image in this way:

```
UIImage* backgroundImage;
backgroundImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"bg.png"];
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:backgroundImage];
```

But, background moves with all other view controller components, while user scroll the table.

Is it possible, to make immovable background, like HTML background?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
UIColor *color= [[[UIColor alloc] initWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Background.png"]] autorelease];
self.tableView.backgroundColor = color;
```

or

```
UIImageView *imageView= [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Background.png"]] autorelease];
imageView.frame = self.tableView.frame

self.tableView.backgroundView = imageView;
```